# Windows 7 Professional downgrade rights to Vista and XP - where to find the media

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, installation, downgrade

MS has announced that Windows 7 Pro onwards downgrade is permissible to Vista and XP.

Statement given below..

"For a limited time of 18 months after the general availability of Windows 7 or the release of a Windows 7 Service Pack, whichever is earlier, the OEM license of Windows 7 Professional and Windows 7 Ultimate will include downgrade rights to Windows XP Professional. After that period the OEM license will enable downgrade rights to Windows Vista Business"

Taken from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fi-FI/w7itprogeneral/thread/9977611a-3810-4cac-bba8-a21418c55942?prof=required)

The question here is if we want to downgrade to XP or Vista does MS provide the media/installer CD/DVD for this?

If not then what are our options?

[Edit]
Of course Windows 7 does provide [XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx), even then if we do want to do a full remove and install of XP or Vista just in case.

Comment: Why would you want to downgrade 7? I can understand downgrading Vista to XP, but 7 is an awesome experience, and it is more secure and usable than XP.

Comment: I suspect there is a lot of overlap with this question.  http://superuser.com/questions/7479/legally-downgrade-windows-vista-home-oem-license

Comment: There is absolutely no overlap, I KNOW it can be done, my query is simple where do we find the media for this, MS?

Comment: @James, well its good to know our options just in case or if I run into any issues in due time.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact Microsoft directly. They'll be able to sort you out.

Comment: I would be leery to downgrade just because they have stated that there are bugs in XP that they will not fix and some of those bugs are terminal issues.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found a great video that will guide you step by step through the process and supplies legit links to download Windows XP legally.

[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NykQrDOIDLM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NykQrDOIDLM&annotation_id=annotation_984223&feature=iv)

Pssst... I would call it an upgrade.. hehe

Comment: Ohh and remember to BACK UP!